# pip install imread fails at Microsoft Visual step

Tags: python, imread

I am trying to install imread to do some image analysis. I am running 2.7.9. When I type pip install imread into powershell, the program runs until it hits some pieces from Microsoft Visual C++. I have attached an image showing where the snag is. Please help.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVzht.jpg

Comment: possible duplicate of [error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat). This problem keeps coming up. We need a canonical question/answer for this.

Answer (score 2):

My advice is: save yourself a lot of trouble and just install a windows binary.

Take a look at the [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#imread) website. Looks like `imread` is available there.

You are running Python 2.7 so grab the `*-cp27-*` matching your Python install (32 or 64 bit).