# How to solve pip installation command

Tags: python-3.x, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I have problem with the python speech recognization problem and audio libraries

This is on the windows system

```
import speach_recognition as sr
r =sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
print("Speak Anything")
audio = r.listen(source)

 try:
    text = r.recognize_google(audio)
    print('you said : {}'.format(text))
except:
    print('sorry could not recognized voice')
```

> C:\Users\DELL> pip install audio Collecting audio   Using cached
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ab/42/b4f04721c5c5bfc196ce156b3c768998ef8c0ae3654ed29ea5020c749a6b/PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz
>   Building wheels for collected packages: audio   Building wheel for
>   pyaudio (setup.py) ... error   ERROR: Complete output from command
>   'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools,
>   tokenize;**file**='"'"'C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1gm3suw5\pyaudio\setup.py'"'"``';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
>   '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
>   bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-ke5zzs2d'
>   --python-tag cp37:   ERROR: running bdist_wheel   running build   running build_py   creating build   creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
>   copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7   running build_ext 
>   building '_portaudio' extension   error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is
>   required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools":
>   https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
>   ----------------------------------------   ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyaudio   Running setup.py clean for pyaudio Failed to build
>   pyaudio Installing collected packages: pyaudio   Running setup.py
>   install for audio ... error
>       ERROR: Complete output from command 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools,
>   tokenize;**file**='"'"'C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1gm3suw5\pyaudio\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
>   '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
>   install --record
>   'C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-e6fzeo61\install-record.txt'
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
>       ERROR: running install
>       running build
>       running build_py
>       creating build
>       creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
>       copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
>       running build_ext
>       building '_portaudio' extension
>       error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools":
>   https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
>       ---------------------------------------- ERROR: Command "'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools,
>   tokenize;**file**='"'"'C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1gm3suw5\pyaudio\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
>   '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
>   install --record
>   'C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-e6fzeo61\install-record.txt'
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1gm3suw5\pyaudio\

Answer (score 0):

As your error indicates:

```
Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
```

You need to install MS Visual C++ 14.0 compiler so that the C++ dependencies can be built ([detailed instruction here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50671800/6573902)).

Another option is (following advice from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28374699/6573902)) to use an *unofficial* library of compiled Windows dependencies for Python packages from [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio).